# DRF - SerializerMethodField for NestedSerializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I've a serializer as follow:-

```
class ABCSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):

    class XYZSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

        a = serializers.CharField(default='abcd') #Try1:- Setting default values.
        b = serializers.IntegerField(default=1)
        c = serializers.ListField(default=[''])

        def get_attribute(self, instance): # Try 2. This works only when many != True.
            return [
            {
            'a': 'abcd',
            'b': 1,
            'c': []
            }]

    field1 = XYZSerializer(many=True)

    def get_field1(self, instance):  # Try 3
        return [
            {
            'a': 'abcd',
            'b': 1,
            'c': []
            }
        ]

    class Meta:
        fields = ('uuid', 'field1')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'uuid': {'source': 'user_id'}
        }
```

I want to return the default value of `XYZSerializer`. How can I do it?

I've tried over-riding `get_attribute` of `XYZSerializer`, but that only works when `many != True`. I've also tried `get_field1`, but to no avail.

How can I pass the default value of `XYZSerializer`?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what happens in each of 3 "tries" you commented?

Comment: Is there any specific reason to define the `XYZSerializer` inside the `ABCSerializer` class?